# 500 Server general error while hosting mvc application

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7

```
500

 Server general error

  The server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the         request, because something went wrong. Please, contact site administrator.

   Resource administration
```

While hosting my application in ISS Server. Some part of the application but it is not showing images and java scripts

When I Host the same in my local iss the application is working fully. I could not get where it is going

I tried in the following ways:

1. Given security permissions to All
2. Checked the application pool
3. I have added exemptions in the web.config to allow users="*"
4. I have added 
   but i was not able to get the detailed error to slove the issue

Comment: You should try to find the details for that error.  Perhaps the application log of the server will have it.  You may also be able to adjust the error settings via the web.config to show you the detailed error message.

Comment: The maximum info i could get was that

Comment: That does happen on occasion -- My general course of action is to put a test.html page in the web application's folder and try to hit that, to rule out anything every wrong with the web site.  If that works, then I'll put a test.aspx page with a very simply "Hello World" script.  Then test that.  Check that the version of the .NET framework / MVC libs you're using are in fact installed/configured on the server.

Comment: There are a few setting that you need to consider to see all the errors (customErrors is just one of them) Try the <httpErrors> setting under the <system.webServer> node of web.config see here. http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httperrors